# InfoPath hide checkbox if RichText value is empty

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-server, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections

I created a one table with lot of columns and rows. Every column has a Rich text box with filters from first page (if dropdown value is equal to X then show text on Rich text box).
Wanna ask how to do. If Rich text box - is empty don't show the checkbox. (Rich text box is also filtering, and right now dropdown value is not equal to X then I'm not showing the text in Rich text box)

How to hide check box if there are no text in Rich text box ?

[image]

Updated:

I tried to make Rule on check box, but the option Hide this control is not active. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can input this checkbox in a section so add formating rule to section .
So I hope this is usefull.

Answer (score 1):

The InfoPath formatting rules don't allow you to hide checkboxes. Typically you'd create a rule on the check box to check if the corresponding rich text field is empty and set the formatting to Hide this control.

You could try to export the source files and manipulate the XSLT and see if that gets you the results you want. I haven't had much success editing the files, your mileage may vary.

The other option is to change the checkbox to a dropdown list control instead which could be hidden.

Comment: Please check, I updated my question.

Comment: Correct, hide is present but it can't be selected, which is why I said it doesn't allow you to do it.